# Xcode user customised NSURL for JSON services

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following NSURL string and I am trying to use the variables to point to a user specific web page to Parse JSON from, What I would like to be able to do is get the information from a UILabel and have it go in the end of URL like so:
 `NSData* carData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.0.0.234:8880/%@", *label.text ]]];`

But I can not seem to be able to do this as "Cannot Pass object interface type 'NSString' by value to variadic method; expected type from format string was 'id'

EDIT: I need this to be able to request a 'username' (cellphone number) from the User in a settings menu and I need to be able to call up this info to be at the end of the URL eg 'www.example.com/01223445

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Cannot Pass object interface type 'NSString' by value to variadic method; expected type from format string was 'id'"

Why are you using `*label.text` ? Which will translate into `*(label.text)` which is a dereferenced NSString. Which is exactly what the compiler is complaining about.

You need to do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.0.0.234:8880/%@", label.text ]]` to get rid of the error. (without the *)

Comment: Thankyou! I had originally done that but I hadn't edited my Label and it just said 'label' so the URL I was getting was 'http://10.0.0.234:8880/label' it's been a long day

Comment: @jakethesnake438 There is no magic, if the text of the 'label' is label, you will get label if you ask what is your text?